# CSV report generation using apex batch

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, csv

I am trying to generate the csv report by fetching the data from ApexTestResult obj. But the column 'message' in the apextestresult obj is overlapping and automatically divided the message and showing in the next column like attached screenshot here [image: message_overlapping].

But This message should be on the same column and not to divide it to next line. Here is the code for csv generation.

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<ApexTestResult> scope) {
    // Append each record to the CSV content
    for (ApexTestResult result : scope) {
        
         String record = result.ID + ',' +
             (result.ApexClass.Name != null ? result.ApexClass.Name : '') + ',' +
             (result.MethodName != null ? result.MethodName : '') + ',' +
             (result.Outcome != null ? result.Outcome : '') + ',' +
             (result.Message != null ? result.Message : '') + ',' +
             (result.TestTimestamp != null ? String.valueOf(result.TestTimestamp) : '') + ',' +
             (result.Runtime != null ? String.valueOf(result.Runtime) : '');
        csvContent += record + newLine;
    }
  
}




private void sendEmailWithCSVAttachment(String csvContent, String[] emails) {
        // Create a new email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        // Set the recipients
        //String[] toAddresses = new String[]{'test@test.com'};
        //email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        email.setToAddresses(emails);

        // Set the email subject
        email.setSubject('Test Execution Result Attached');

        // Set the email body
        email.setPlainTextBody('Please find attached Test Execution Result CSV file.');

        // Convert CSV content to Blob
        Blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(csvContent);

        // Create a new attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('ApexTestResults.csv');
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        attachment.setBody(csvBlob);

        // Attach the CSV file to the email
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attachment});

        // Send the email
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
    }
```

Comment: This approach will break: 1. You will find you run out of heap space for your batch, and it will fail, if you have a large set of data to process and you're storing the `csvContent` as state in your `Database.Stateful` batch. 2. Using email addresses for recipients instead of user IDs means you will consume daily email limits.

Answer (score 2):

CSV uses quotes to escape newlines, so you need to, too. Use the `escapeCSV()` method:

```
String record = result.ID + ',' +
    (result.ApexClass.Name != null ? result.ApexClass.Name : '') + ',' +
    (result.MethodName != null ? result.MethodName : '') + ',' +
    (result.Outcome != null ? result.Outcome : '') + ',' +
    (result.Message != null ? result.Message.escapeCSV() : '') + ',' +
    (result.TestTimestamp != null ? String.valueOf(result.TestTimestamp) : '') + ',' +
    (result.Runtime != null ? String.valueOf(result.Runtime) : '');
```

This will automatically add quotes, if necessary, to make the CSV properly readable by external applications.